# How to enable auto answer plugin by attribute

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I'm trying to use [this documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/messaging/faq-and-troubleshooting) in order to build a plugin to auto accept an inbound call. What I also want is the ability to turn auto answer on/off by a certain worker attribute. Here's what I have so far in my `init(flex, manager) method` :

```
if(manager.workerClient.attributes.[attribute name].includes('[attribute name')) {
    manager.workerClient.on('reservationCreated', reservation => {
         if (reservation.task.attributes.autoAnswer === 'true') {
           flex.Actions.invokeAction('AcceptTask', {sid: reservation.sid});
           flex.Actions.invokeAction('SelectTask', {sid: reservation.sid});
         }
    });
}
```

I've read through the documentation on accessing worker attributes and think I'm fine with getting the attribute name. However, I'm unsure of the auto answer portion.

Comment: That looks right to me. Is it working for you? Or are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: @philnash it's not working for me. I've only touched the plugin.js file though, do I need to do anything else to set up the plugin? Like modify the appConfig.js file? I'm testing it locally and no task is auto accepting.

Comment: Have you followed the [guide for building your own plugin, including running the example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin)? Are you able to log out when a reservation comes in? What if you remove the attribute check?

Comment: I meant `console.log` to see that your code is getting called.

Comment: @philnash whoops.. doesn't look like the code is being called on('reservationCreated', reservation =>

Comment: I have [an example of auto answering an incoming call here](https://github.com/philnash/plugin-flex-webinar/blob/main/src/FlexWebinarPlugin.js#L28-L31), but it looks very similar to yours. Is there anything in my example plugin different to yours? How are you running Flex with the plugin?

Comment: @philnash I added your code snippet to my plugin and it seems to work when I run it on localhost:3000 with url:'/plugins' in appConfig.js (only runs that plugin). However, when I run it locally and have url:' ' in appConfig.js (so it runs with all of my plugins) it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are missing part of your comment?

Comment: @philnash Just updated my comment!

Comment: I think when you remove the plugins URL it gets the information about the available plugins from a request to flex.twilio.com/plugins and if you have not deployed your plugin, then it won't be present.

Comment: @philnash Just deployed and release the plugin and it works. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your code looks correct, I have a similar [example that I've used before here](https://github.com/philnash/plugin-flex-webinar/blob/main/src/FlexWebinarPlugin.js#L28-L31).

After discussing with you in the comments, if you set the plugins `url` to an empty string or null, then Flex will make an API request to look for plugins that it should load at `flex.twilio.com/plugins`, which only comprises of plugins that you have deployed. You should either set the `url` to your local `/plugins` to load the local version. Or you should deploy your plugin so that it can be loaded from `flex.twilio.com/plugins` in your environment.